# How to compile Solaris executable under Debian?

Tags: debian, compiling, solaris, c++, compiler

I have a SSH account at my university's computer in which I can only compile with gcc 4.4.7, which doesn't compatible with my C++ 11 code (I don't have the rights to install/update software). In my computer I have Debian but the program that I compiled in Debian is not compatible with Solaris.

Can I compile my source code under Debian to make work it with Solaris somehow?
Or is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: What Solaris release? On what architecture (SPARC or x86)?

Answer (score 3):

You could install VirtualBox (or some other virtual machine software) on your Debian machine, and install Solaris in *that*.  Oracle (the vendor) provides [downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/index.html).

If the university's computer is compatible (x86-based, similar version), it would be possible to compile locally and use the executables on the other machine.

Comment: Where can I get Solaris OS installer?

Comment: It sounds like the issue is with the compiler and code rather than with having access Solaris. A cross-compiler for compiling C++11 code for Solaris on Debian, or installing a C++11-capable compiler in a home directory and compile static binaries would be a better solution.

Comment: Cross compilers to platforms such as Solaris are less common than you might suppose (generally cross compilers are available for a *few* of the interesting low-capability targets).  It would be a good [learning exercise](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~jparr090/crosscompile.shtml), but a dedicated machine is best practice.

Comment: Just to say I made installing and setting up a Solaris 11.3 VM in VirtualBox my weekend project, and there's at least GCC 5.4 available to be installed through the package manager. `g++` 5.4 is supposed to handle C++11 ([ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011)).

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for, as Thomas Dickey posted, [is a *cross compiler*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

They're not *difficult* to do, but they are very tedious to set up and keep set up properly, because there are a *lot* of dependencies on the target system that have to be accounted for in order to build a proper executable.

What are some of those dependencies?  Just off the top of my head:

1. First, your target system is likely [a *hosted environment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825151/is-there-a-meaningful-distinction-between-freestanding-and-hosted-implementation) so your cross compiler would need to provide executable start-up code/binaries to allow the target system to actually get to the point of calling your `main()` function.
2. There are a lot of *implementation-defined* details on the target system, such as "How big is a `long`".  Those can differ, so you need, for lack of a better word - the target *implementation*.  In general, that means at least *all* the header files for your target system that are "part of the implementation". Determining which ones you need and which ones you don't is a tedious task at best.  So just grab all of them, right?  Well, that increases the number of dependencies you have to worry about.
3. So now you can compile - but you can't *link* without the target systems libraries (this relates back to #1 above, but even *more* is needed). While in theory you can link with just the target systems *static* libraries and without the target systems *dynamic* libraries, without *all* the libraries you can't really be certain the binary produced by your cross-compiler won't fail with a "missing symbol" error when you try to run it on your target system.

So you need the header files, the libraries, and the startup binaries/code for your target system to create a cross-compiler - and once you get it set up, you have to *maintain* it - if the target system gets patched in a way that impacts your cross-compiler, you need to replicate those changes in your compiler.  How do you determine that patch "123456" or RPM "abc" impacts your cross compiler?

And I probably missed a whole lot.

It should be pretty obvious why no one bothers with cross compilers where the target system is something that's *easy* to create an instance of like Linux/Solaris/Windows/BSD on x86 hardware, and even why when the target system is something harder (like Solaris on SPARC) almost everyone with a need to compile for that target just buys some low-end compatible hardware for compiling on.